# Why does the Docker for Tensorflow GPU container fall back to CPU?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I've followed the instructions for setting up Tensorflow with a GPU, and tried the provided tests for Docker with NVIDIA support and for the Tensorflow Docker image, and they all pass, but when I try to run useful code, it falls back to the CPU. I get the following messages:

```
2021-01-04 19:49:01.589288: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-01-04 19:49:05.077345: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-04 19:49:05.077467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-01-04 19:49:05.077477: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (-1)
2021-01-04 19:49:05.077495: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:163] no NVIDIA GPU device is present: /dev/nvidia0 does not exist
2021-01-04 19:49:05.078801: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-04 19:49:06.133307: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-01-04 19:49:06.153276: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 3493365000 Hz
```

Note that I get an "UNKNOWN ERROR" when it tries to call cuInit. What causes this problem? The program I'm trying to run works fine on the CPU, but I've invested a lot of money in GPUs to run it faster.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the tests you have used to confirm the setup is correct? What do you get when you run `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in the image, and not the way you use it? Can you share what you did before the error message appear?

Comment: When I run the test command from the instructions for setting it up (docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu \
   python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))") I get a lot of messages indicating that it was successful. When I try to run bash in a session using the same options 9except --rm, which I omitted because I may need access to the container afterward), I get what I copied above.

Comment: nvidia-smi works on the host, but the command isn't found inside the docker container.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure where the problem is; I just asked why I'm getting this behaviour from it, not what was wrong with it.

Comment: Did you install 'nvidia-docker' before pulling tensorflow-gpu image. Please follow the instructions mentioned https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker#tensorflow_docker_requirements. Thanks!